# Parameter validation error for the CSRFGENERATETOKEN function

Tags: coldfusion-11

In Coldfusion 11 Update 15 the following piece of code errors with:

A built-in ColdFusion function cannot accept an assignment statement as a parameter, although it can accept expressions. For example, CSRFGENERATETOKEN(d=a*b) is not acceptable.

```
<cfset nonce = csrfGenerateToken( forceNew = true )>
```

It was working fine up until the time IT updated our server to Update 15

Comment: So it looks like Adobe did not support named parameters in built-in functions until the 2018 release. They must have implemented an exception for when someone attempts to use it in prior versions. 

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/using/whats-new.html#named

Comment: Under which CF 11 version did this code actually work?  I tried CF11 versions back to 11,0,05,302575 and a few CF10 versions, and it throws that same error in all of them.